# appending to string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to append my string in one line of code.
Is there any `stringByAppendingStrings`?

```
NSString *url=[url stringByAppendingString:changeString];
url=[url stringByAppendingString:@"&latitude=52.3328117&longitude=4.878836"];
url=[url stringByAppendingString:@"time=2:00"];
```

Comment: Why does it have to be one line? I doubt it would increase readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use stringWithFormat if you're creating the string all at once.

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", string1, string2, string3];
```

Comment: dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d/%d", currentSelectDate.day, currentSelectDate.month, currentSelectDate.year];
This works fine

Answer (score 3):

Use NSMutableString to get the work done.

Check out the documentation for more information to edit any Mutable String

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@&latitude=52.3328117&longitude=4.878836time=2:00" , url, changeString]
```